# Memory management quirks! in relation to NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have been dabbling a lot with Objective C off late, and memory management and understanding it's nuances is a challenge so far.

I comprehend that every object I create, I have it's ownership and that I must release it once I am done using it? (do correct if I am wrong). Onto the core problem:

Let's say I have a method/message called `-(void)doSomething;`
The interface has a Boolean variable say turn and `doSomething` needs to utilize the value of turn to change the value present in an `NSMutableArray`, something to the effect off:

```
[[matrix objectAtIndex:1] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:turn];
```

Quite clearly this will not work, since 'turn' is not an object. So I believe the way forward is to create an `NSNumber` object initialized as `BOOL` value, using the value in turn.

The `-(void)doSomething` message is passed several times. This would mean that each time it is sent to the receiver, the `NSNumber` object is being re-created and its value being altered (I think this is where it all gets loony for me).

My question, now should I go ahead and release the `NSNumber` object every time the message is sent to the receiver? Essentially I need a great brain dump here on the memory management challenge I am foreseeing!!!

P.S: Writing this out, I do think I should go ahead and release the object at the end of each message call, but since I typed it out, I would rather get your opinions as well.

Thanks a megaton folks!

Answer (score 1):

NSArrays handle their own memory management. Once you add an object to an array it will retain it until it is removed from the array.

```
[[matrix objectAtIndex:1] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:turn];
```

Here you have added 'turn' to the array, so it will retain it. If you have ownership of this object you can now release it; If you created it with a convenience method it was already auto released.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:turn];
```

creates autoreleased `NSNumber` object. That means it's released once it goes out of scope. Then this call:

```
[[matrix objectAtIndex:1] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:turn]];
```

sets a new object in an array. The array retains its objects, so your `NSNumber` representation of `turn` will be still valid when it's autoreleased (it was previously retained by the array) and will have no connection with the future values of `turn`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use ARC to avoid manual memory management.

But without ARC, if you pass an object from one method to another, it is *not* re-created, but the address to the object is passed to the method.

In your case you should create an autoreleased NSNumber object pass it through all your methods, and once it is stored in your array, the array retains it for you.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on NJones answers, Cocoa has a well defined set of conventions for object ownership that you can see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). Finally objects are pointers so when you pass them around only pointers are copied, not the value that you are pointing to.